# dovecot:Failed to lookup domain owner

Tags: dovecot

Can't get mails then connected with The Bat!
Server sends: 
*-ERR Authentication failed.*
and the record in maillog is:
*dovecot: auth(default): Failed to lookup domain owner of*

The problem occurred after I rebuild the Apache.
Where can be problem?

Answer (score 0):

As hoster support said:

The reason was that the hostname was the same as domain. The mail server tried to authenticate agains system users for the VPS instead of virtual users for the domain.